# Windows Phone 8 Localize String Variable

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization

I am rather new to Windows Phone development and I have hit a snag while trying to localize my app for a few different languages.  I am using the AppResources.resx for each language to localize strings that are static however I can't seem to figure out how to localize a dynamically created string variable.  For example...

String date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd");

This would return "March 6".  But when the device's language is set to Spanish I want to display "6 de Marzo" not "March 6". Any ideas on how to go about doing this? Just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it exists also in WinPhone8, but you could try to use

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.MonthDayPattern);
```

Comment: That did the trick.  A lot easier than I thought.  Thanks a million.